# Cannot populate ArrayAdapter with ArrayList

Tags: android

I've recently been following a [tutorial](http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/simple-android-json-parsing-example-with-output-into-listactivity/) about getting from a webserver, interpreting it and then displaying it and I have ran into some issues. I can't seem to populate the ArrayAdapter with the *twitterFeed* variable no matter how hard I try. Yesterday I was told to run the class *fetchTwitterPublicTimeline* on another thread and I have done that but can't populate the ArrayAdapter. The error that I receive when I hover over the *twitterFeed* variable in *setListAdapter* I get the error 'twitterFeed cannot be resolved' which makes me believe that it might not be running the class or not passing the variable out properly.My code is below and thanks!

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.simplebrowser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void run() {
            ArrayList<String> twitterFeed = fetchTwitterPublicTimeline();

        }

    };

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, twitterFeed));  
  }


public ArrayList<String> fetchTwitterPublicTimeline() {
      ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

      try {
          URL twitter = new URL("http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json");
          URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));
          String line;

          while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
              JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
              for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                  listItems.add(jo.getString("text"));
              }
          }
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (JSONException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return listItems;

  } 


}
```

Edit: Uncommented the handler as that was a mistake. Issue still not resolved.

Comment: do you have network access permission on your manifest.xml?

Comment: Yep I have INTERNET access in there.

Comment: Looks like this shouldn't even compile, `twitterFeed` is in an anonymous inner class, makes sense you can't get a ref to it in your `MainActivity`.